# How to prove that angles on straight line add up to 180 degrees?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Hi 
 I want to know how to prove that angles on straight line add up to 180 degrees, WITHOUT using theorems that their proofs use the theorem i want to prove, and without using theroems that their proofs contain use of another theorem, and  this theorem proof contains the fact i want to prove. 
I think you got what i mean, i want to know how people figured this out, and of course they did not have theorems that sum of angles on straight line implies - because they didn't know it yet. 
what i tried to do, is take a straight line AB, take a point O on AB such that AO=BO=R, and build a circle with center O and radius R. 
http://sketchtoy.com/68586942 look here what i mean and look at the angles named alpha and beta (sorry for the bad drawing) 
I can see that alpha+beta=360 because of the defenition of degree. 
but how can I know that alpha=beta? 
if i can prove that the diameter AB cuts the circle to two equale arcs, i can know that alpha=beta and then alpha=beta=180, it is very intuitive that this is the case but how can i prove it? thanks!

Comment: A straight line can be considered as an $180$° - angle. I do not get which kind of proof you are looking for. If the actual problem is something else, you should edit the title.

Comment: im looking for proof that the sum of angles on a straight line=180 degrees

Comment: There cannot be no proof for definitions, assumptions or axioms.

Comment: @Narasimham but this is not a definition, assumption or axiom (i think), is it?

Comment: It is definition of a half turn, if you consider the pivot/fulcrum.

Answer (score 1):

> but how can I know that alpha=beta?

$\alpha=\beta$ because your figure stays the same when you mirror it w.r.t. the line.

Comment: yeah sure, but how could you know that this is exactly mirrored? you can see that i mentioned that if i could prove that the diameter cuts the circle into two equal semi circles (aka-the draw is symmetrical, and the upper half mirrored=lower half) i would be able to solve the problem, but how could you be sure that the two arcs are equal? @Wouter

Answer (score 1):

When you draw a circle whose center is on your straight line the circle is divided into two equal  semi-circles.

The total degree of a circle is by definition $360$ degrees.

Thus each semi circle accounts for $180$ degrees.

That is the central angle is also $180$ degrees.

Thus the straight line add up to $180$ degrees.

Comment: that is exactly why i ask - how can you prove that there are two equal semi circles?

Comment: You may reflect one semi circle on the other one and use definition of circle to see each point of one covers exactly one point of the other because the distance from the center is the same at every point of the circle.

Comment: Riaxi-kermani yeah but this is kind of intuitive approach isn't it? can you please show me a formal proof that each point on the upper half has a symmetrical point on the lower half?

Comment: Let your line be the x_axis and the center of your circle be the origin. define a function f(x,y)=(x,-y) from the upper semi circle onto the  lower one. This is a one-to-one function.

Comment: is that because the equation of the circle is x^2+y^2=R^2 and both x,y and x,-y satisfy the equation?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The graph is symmetric with respect to the x-axis because f(x,-y)=f(x,y).

Comment: okay, thank you!